# Android - Layout in JAVA File

Tags: android

As per my requirement, i should give the orientation in horizontal only, if i give 3 sentences in 3 text views, if there is no space for third sentence then it should come in the next line in the first position ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 15, 10, 10);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;     

    TextView tvTextsecond = new TextView(this);
    tvTextsecond.setText("Heywhatrudoingtoday");
    tvTextsecond.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tvTextsecond.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    tvTextsecond.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    TextView tvTextthird = new TextView(this);
    tvTextthird.setText("Haiitssundaytowork");
    tvTextthird.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tvTextthird.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    tvTextthird.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    TextView tvTextfourth = new TextView(this);
    tvTextfourth.setText("Owebullshitruuselessfellow");
    tvTextfourth.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tvTextfourth.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    tvTextfourth.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    layout.addView(tvTextsecond);
    layout.addView(tvTextthird);
    layout.addView(tvTextfourth);

}

private void findViewById() {

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.flowLayout);

}
```

}

Comment: isn't that exactly what the LinearLayout does when telling it to wrap its contents?

Comment: I cant understand ur question Timothy .

I need to do all the wrap layout properties in linear layout.

For Example :  if i give 3 sentences in 3 text views, if there is no space for third sentence then it should come in the next line in the first position ...

Comment: Other than linear layout how to solve this query, give me a perfect solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear Layout doesn't behave that way. If there is no space, it would go out of your display area. So, for your requirement, you can't use Linear Layout here.